# ffmpeg: CP1252: Invalid argument

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitles, charset

I'm trying to burn subtitles into a video. My subtitles are in CP1252 and I have this error, I don't know why:

> `[NULL @ 0x5fe0040] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'CP1252'
>   CP1252: Invalid argument`

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -acodec aac -ar 48000 -ab 128k -ac 2 -s 720x404 -vcodec libx264 -level 3.1 -tune film -preset slow -crf 19 -vf -sub_charenc CP1252 subtitles=sub.srt output.mp4
```

Note: If I delete `-sub_charenc CP1252` it works but I have subtitles problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is malformed. The `sub_charenc` is a decoder option and applies when the subtitle file is fed as a regular input. The subtitle filter, however, takes in its input directly.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf subtitles=sub.srt:charenc=CP1252
       -s 720x404 -c:v libx264 -level 3.1 -tune film -preset slow -crf 19  
       -c:a aac -ar 48000 -b:a 128k -ac 2 output.mp4
```

You may have to quote the codepage i.e. `'CP1252'` or `"CP1252"`

Comment: Big thank you. Your response really help me.

Comment: I was also trying to use -sub_charenc, and this answer really helped me (using :charenc=  immediately after the srt file works). Thank you!